# How to list all the disk in a listview using pyqt5?

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qt5, pyqt5

I have a QListView in which i would i like to show all the disks name.Either mounted or not . If it's not mounted it will ask me for password. I looked up in QStorageInfo class but didn't get it.
Can you tell me how to use it so it will work in mac, linux and in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Class QStorageInfo has static method [mountedVolumes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html#mountedVolumes) that returns list of currently mounted drivers. If you use QListView  you should create model that can operate this data. As fast solution you can use QListWidget like this:

```
for(const auto &storage :  QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()) {
  listWidget->addItem(storage.name());
}
```

Qt doesn't have classes or methods to mount drivers. You can use udev library for that in Linux.

*P.S. sorry for c++ code, i don't think it's a problem to convert it to python code.*